Why php exec() using git returns an empty response, and why result_code = 1
I'm trying to get the git logs, and display the latest update date in the admin panel. But all attempts to reach git with functions: exec, shell_exec, system, passthru do not give me results even on the git --version command.
What am I doing wrong? rights to the folder ./git tried to issue, but I don't think the rights are the problem. Perhaps the environment variables are incorrect. Windows 10 OS
$output = [];
exec('git --version', $output, $result_code);
$output2 = shell_exec('git --version');
$last_line = system('git --version', $result_code2);
$ff = passthru('git --version', $result_code3);
var_dump($output, $result_code, $output2, $last_line, $result_code2, $ff, $result_code3);

GitHelper.php:18:
array (size=0)
  empty
GitHelper.php:18:int 1
GitHelper.php:18:null
GitHelper.php:18:string '' (length=0)
GitHelper.php:18:int 1
GitHelper.php:18:null
GitHelper.php:18:int 1


1 means operation not permitted.

Can you provide a [mcve], please? Does your code have a <?php header? How do you call your code? Is git in your PATH?

@UlrichEckhardt <?php it is registered. Should I drop the request headers? in the PATH:
C:\OSPanel\modules\PHP-8.2\PHP
C:\Program Files
\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
In the console, all commands work out as they should

@shingo you're right, my mistake

Is it in PATH? (of your PHP process. It doesn't matter what PATH is in your console)

@knittl Environment variables -> PATH. This is what I have prescribed. If I run the exec('php --version', $output, $result_code); I get the result about the version. When I do git --version, I get an empty response.

FWIW, none of these commands will capture messages sent to STDERR. You may want to redirect that to STDOUT.

@ÁlvaroGonzález where should I specify the STDOUT constant? Can you give me an example of how I can get this?

It isn't a constant, it's a feature of most shells: How to Redirect stderr to stdout in Bash. I can't find a good link for cmd.exe but I think the syntax is the same.

@Tiv just because your php's process PATH contains php itself doesn't mean that it contains git. What does echo $_ENV['PATH'] print and does it include the directory of the git binary?

@knittl I don't see git here C:\OSPanel\bin;C:\OSPanel\modules\PHP-8.1\Apache\bin;C:\OSPanel\modules\PHP-8.1\PHP;C:\OSPanel\data\PHP-8.1\default\composer\vendor\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0. how do I add it here?

You write "request headers", which suggests you're using some kind of webserver, but you don't say which one and whether calling PHP from the commandline or from a different user account (like the webserver's perhaps) make a difference.

I've solved the problem. You need to open the osp 6 module settings (C:\OSPanel\config\PHP-x .x\default\settings.ini) and add the necessary paths for the PATH variable there. After that, you need to restart the module.
